# php mysql call returns unknow domain name

Tags: mysql, centos

I have a webserver which connect to mysql database server over WAN.

The database user gets denied with domain name:

```
SELECT command denied to user 'xxxxxx'@'safe.closedoor.net' for table 'xxxxx'
```

i XXX the names which are not relevant.
it's the domain name which I don't get; its not what the server is called.
Googling that name doesn't give me any results.

Both servers are Centos 6

Does anybody know where this name is stored on the machine? (its not the domain I would like to authorize for mysql access)

Comment: it seems like user don't have full privilege to do queries on the table

Comment: is your webserver on your local LAN and the mysql server is remote?  you'll need to add privileges for your user at your external IP address to the mysql server.

Comment: The domain name belongs to the computer from which you are connecting to the mysql server, as seen by the mysql server.

Comment: The name probably comes from the reverse DNS of the client's IP.

Answer (score 0):

Barmar was right.
I used website for dns lookup ( https://remote.12dt.com/lookup.php )
and it showed me "safe.closedoor.net" for that IP.